# HTML-Snippet on greatest hits page

Tags: bug, status-completed, greatest-hits

I just checked the [greatest hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits) page at SO and saw this:

[image: unrendered HTML with freehand cycles]

I don't think this should look like that. Maybe more like that?

[image: Firebug FTW. WITH FREEHAND CYCLES!!!11eleven]

Comment: Since this is a part of SO main, not of the chat, this will probably get an official response.

Comment: I know someone who wrote a script (for IRC) that answers "ask2ask" questions with "You already did". The logic is based on when the user joined, if he said anything else and some delay to let the user provide extra info. I wonder if that is forbidden.

Comment: Why  should it be forbidden? The official complaint is against the bot initiating communication (or anyone but the newcomer, by extension?), as far as I understand.

Comment: [Wheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)

Comment: [Here is archived copy of a proper page version](http://web.archive.org/web/20130512070313/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was due to a new *caching* mechanism we're implementing on localized pages.

It'll be fixed in build rev `2013.11.13.1631` on meta and `2013.11.13.1150` on sites.

Comment: Caching is hard...