# Eeeks! Questions and Unanswered tabs are down on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

Unable to access [Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) and [Unanswered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) tabs on Meta.  I see a somewhat familiar *Windows WER* dialog.

> [image]

Comment: Yes, I see the same.

Comment: The lack of cats working on my problem concerns me that the problem will not be sorted

Comment: Who? What? When? Where? Why? How?

Comment: If you try to access questions, it'll mess up, but for some reason meta.stackoverflow.com is fine

Comment: Questions and Unanswered are stuffed up, but nothing else it seems. rev 2013.11.13.1630

Comment: And the horrifically donvoted rants aren't shown on the main page, and whats the fun of that!?

Comment: @RichardTingle: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion

Comment: @RichardTingle cats, unicorns and devs doing funny things can [be found here on Stack Overflow error page](http://stackoverflow.com/error). ;-) ([full list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203635/152859))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for the wheel of blame. My fault..

Related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207197/html-snippet-on-greatest-hits-page). Fix on it's way.

As already said, it's *always* caching....

Comment: Seems to be fixed.  Great!

Comment: Now that you're on a bug roll, is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207198/152859) your fault too? ;)

Comment: unfortunately we'd have to consolidate the wheel of blame for that one... but no worries, a fix is on it's way ;)